# Exception while opening an Excel file

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

I have an Excel file which gives error while opening it manually:

`excel found unreadable content in *****.xlsx. Do you want to recover the content of this workbook? If you trust this workbook click yes.`

If I click yes, I can open it in usual way, but if I use:

```
Excel.Application oExcelApp;
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

I am getting a COMException:

`Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

How to handle this exception. How can I make it open or show that error which is shown everytime I open it manually.

I am using MS Office 2010.

Comment: Are you closing your excel application after you use it in your code?

Comment: @ToonCasteele I am showing it to user. User can close it whenever he wants. Or shall I close it everytime user hits close button? Is it causing the problem?

Comment: Check your running processes in task manager (not applications, processes), see if there are multiple instances of excel there.

Comment: @ToonCasteele I understood what you are trying to say. Yes. I am closing the previous excel file. Problem here is, I can open few files perfectly, and few I cant(which give that error when I try to open it manually). Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this? Having the same problem. One book opens, the other doesn't...

Comment: @JelleOosterbosch You have to change one of the flags in `Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);` to true/false. Don't remember which one. Sorry!

Comment: @shrigurunayak: I was using ExcelLibrary aswell, and appareantly, the file size was just to litte..

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your 4th parameter type to XlFileFormat (enumeration) and choose the a fitting value ([enum description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017(v=office.15).aspx)). Maybe 5 (***xlWK1*** value in enum) is the wrong one...

for example

```
Excel.Application oExcelApp;
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```